# innerHTML works jQuery html() doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I can't get **jQuery html()** function to work. I've tried the following:

1. Find a specific div:

   `var div = $("#divId");`

   Outcome: works
2. Test that i can use it with jQuery:

   `alert($(div).attr("id"));`

   Outcome: works; the id is presented
3. Get the html within the div:

   `alert($(div).html());`

   Outcome: does not work; empty alert
4. Get the html within the div with innerHTML:

   `alert(document.getElementById($(div).attr("id")).innerHTML);`

   Outcome: works; the div content is presented in the alert

The actual code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var autocomp = namespace('mx.autocomp');

autocomp.overlay = (function() {

    var formId;
    var $searchValueComp;
    var $searchResultComp;

    function init(inFormId, inSearchValue){
        formId = inFormId;
        $searchValueComp = $("#"+inFormId).find("[id$="+inSearchValue+"]");
        $searchResultComp = $("#"+inFormId).find("[id$=searchResult]");
    }

    function handleOverlay(){
        var fn = window[formId + "OverlayWid"];
        var result = document.getElementById($searchResultComp.attr("id")).innerHTML;

        if($searchValueComp.val().length==0){
            fn.hide();
        }

        // Test - This does not work as I get an empty alert
        alert($searchResultComp.html());

        // Edit1: New test, this works.
        // When I use this javascript, I start with initializing the script from the page
        // using the "init(inFormId, inSearchValue)" function. The handleOverlay() function
        // is called through the "oncomplete='mx.autocomp.overlay.handleOverlay();'" of a
        // p:remoteCommand that executes a search in the db and then update the div called
        // "searchResultComp".
        //
        // Only reason I can think of why the code below works is that the jQuery object $test 
        // is created after the div called "searchValueComp" has been updated by p:remoteCommand.
        // However, I don't understand why the jquery object "searchValueComp" wouldn't have
        // access to the same content as it should look for it first when the html() function 
        // is called. Or is the content of the div searchValueComp set immediately when the 
        // object is created in the "init" function?
        var $test = $("#"+formId).find("[id$=searchResult]");
        alert($test.html());

        // I need to check if the div: "searchResultComp" has any content. 
        // As I don't get $searchResultComp.html() to work, I'm forced to 
        // use the "getElementById" way instead. 
        if(result.length==0){
            fn.hide();
        }else{
            fn.show();
        }

    }

    function print(text){
        $("#textCheck").prepend(text + '\n');
    }

    return {
        handleOverlay: handleOverlay,
        init: init
    };

})();

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Care to provide a jsfiddle? It must be something wrong with some other code.

Comment: Just a detail: you don't need to wrap the *variable* `div` inside `$()` since you've already defined it as a jQuery object `$("#divId")`

Comment: Do not rewrap a jQuery object, that is a waste. `var div = $("#divId"); var id = div.attr("id"); var html = div.html();`

Comment: seems to work here: http://plnkr.co/edit/bjc1oxDw3k5dU8OPCOdx?p=preview

Comment: Use `div.html()` instead `$(div).html` because you already wrapped the div element into the jQuery namespace.

Comment: Your code works as-is. http://jsfiddle.net/ggMf6/ Unless you can provide proof of it not working in a way that we can test/recreate we can't help you.

Comment: Where is .html in your newly added code?  how were you using it?

Comment: I've added the code that gives me problem. It's under the "Test" comment. I would like to use such a statement instead of the "result" variable to check if the div has any content.

Comment: What does this give you? `alert($("[id=" + $searchResultComp.attr("id") + "]").length)`

Comment: Also, this: `$searchValueComp.text.length` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @KevinB: I get: "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id=autoTestForm:j_idt83:searchResult]" when testing that. I've also changed from "text" to "val()" as you pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: I had exactly this problem and it was because I was double wrapping my selectors with $(), so use div.html() not $(div).html()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Campbell gave me the answer in a follow-up question to this one: [Is the "content" of a jquery object set immediately at creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498059/is-the-content-of-a-jquery-object-set-immediately-at-creation/14498348#14498348)

Evidently, I must re-initialize the variable searchResultComp to get the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <select class="myclass">...</select>
    <select class="myotherclass">...</select>
</div>
```

***JS CODE***

```
var $div = $('div');
alert($div.html());
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsc78/3/)**

Answer (score -1):

When assigning jQuery objects to variables it's often common to start the variable with a `$` to make it stand out as a jQuery object. This doesn' affect your code but makes it easier from a developer point of view.

```
var $div = $('div');
```

To get the html do the following:

```
$div.html();
```

Comment: i'm not the dv, but this clearly isn't the reason his code isn't working. although it isn't a bad suggestion.

Comment: This works though. The problem is likely a syntax error by the developer. Without seeing more code it's impossible to help.

Comment: Yes but I was offering a cleaner alternative, which is a valid answer. If the original question has working code then the question should be down voted. Not my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to quote the div, like this:

```
$("div").html();
```

Also, if you have multiple div elements on the page you'll want to specify one. You can do this by adding a class, or using .eq() to filter the results.

Here's an example.
http://jsfiddle.net/W8qkE/

Comment: Since the procedure the OP outlines above uses div as a variable for $('#divId'), it should still work. There has to be something else wrong.